# Mongoose/MongoDB - findOneAndDelete returns success even if the item has already been deleted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I do a delete request for the api below it works sorta, but if I were to call
'api/admin/deleteUsers/12345' two times in a row, I get two success responses.

How can I fix it so that the second time I call it, it returns an error since the first request should delete the entry.

I thought it would just send the message 'Item not found' the second time called.  The db shows the item getting deleted, but it just seems like the 'findOneAndDelete' still thinks that row exists, but it doesn't.

I'm confused, probably a stupid/silly error on my part, can someone show me?

```
router.delete('/api/admin/deleteUsers/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  //Delete id 
  users.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id}, function (err) {
    if (!err)  {
        res.send("Id " + req.params.id + " has been deleted");
    } else {
        res.send('Item not found');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is `console.log(err)` immediately after `findOneAndDelete`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem I see here is when you use findOneAndDelete() on item that already deleted mongoose will give you null without any error and this possible operation and you won't get any error. So in callback there is no error .

The solution is use below code it will work . You can validate that user value is null or not .

```
router.delete('/api/admin/deleteUsers/:id', async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = await users.findOneAndDelete({ _id: req.params.id });
    console.log('test user is :', user);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send('Item not found');
    }
    return res.status(200).send("Id " + req.params.id + " has been deleted");
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json(err);
  }
});
```

I implemented this in Promise way but you can implement as you want .
You can also see the null value of user when user already deleted in console